# Store Photos(JPG) in snowflake Binary data Type

Tags: binary, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

what are the steps to store the photos (size <1MB) in snowflake binary data type?

Comment: Why do you want to store photos in an analytical database such as Snowflake? What are you planning to do with the data once you've managed to get it in to Snowflake?

Comment: 1) create a table with a binary column. 2) Load the binary column with binary data.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to encode your images into HEX or BASE64 and then load them into a BINARY column.  See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/binary-input-output.html for more details.  As others have mentioned, this isn't a great fit for Snowflake and you may want to consider just storing references to the images (paths/urls) and storing them elsewhere.

Here is one way to store an image using the Python connector.

```
import snowflake.connector
import base64
import requests


# Assumes create or replace TABLE IMAGE (C1 BINARY);

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(**your_params)

sql = f"""insert into image values (to_binary('{base64.b64encode(requests.get('https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com').content).decode('ascii')}', 'BASE64'));"""
conn.cursor().execute(sql)

# Optionally, to display the image
import io
from PIL import Image
im = conn.cursor().execute("select * from image").fetchall()
with io.BytesIO(im[0][0]) as f:
    display(Image.open(f))
```